# SSH через USB к Raspberry pi 4 B

Tags: ssh, usb, raspberry-pi, kali-linux

как дать доступ ssh через usb к андроиду. Хочу иметь доступ к консоли pi (у меня на ней Kali) с телефона, но точку доступа включать не хочу, а хочу подключить pi и телефон через usb и таким образом иметь доступ к консоли pi

Comment: https://gist.github.com/gbaman/50b6cca61dd1c3f88f41 (и [newer method](https://gist.github.com/gbaman/975e2db164b3ca2b51ae11e45e8fd40a))

Comment: Мне нужен доступ с Android а не с PC

Comment: ну, ладно, с некоторой натяжкой android можно назвать и «операционной системой». но «personal computer» — это точно не операционная система. но это так, лирика. главное: никакой операционно-системной специфики в подключении к usb-эмулятору ethernet-адаптера вообще-то нет.

Comment: А, спасибо не знал

Comment: не сработало к сожелению